# How to change spree gem order mail format in spree based application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, spree

I am new to spree gem and ruby on rails.I am using spree gem in my application. Now I want to change order mail format but I am not able to change that. Can anyone who suggest me from where I should initiate. I need some guidance..??

Answer (score 0):

What is your Spree version? Could you check forks of spree-html-email gem? I bet you will find right version for you Spree instance.

https://github.com/joshnuss/spree-html-email/network